# Density chart with several labelled geom_vline() as means in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to create a density chart showing the distribution of the variable "approval_gov". Now I want to have dashed lines showing the mean of all respondents, plus the means of different independent variables like gender, age cohorts and income levels. The labels should include the mean and the name of the group (e.g. Male: mean). Or they should include only the means and the group name in a legend. I tried several approchaes, but I only managed to get a dashed line for the mean in general, but without any label.

These are the first 20 rows:

```
lebanon <- structure(list(gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor"), approval_gov = c(9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 2L
), age_cat = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("18-29", 
"30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60 and above"), class = "factor"), 
    income_recoded = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Low income", 
    "Middle income", "High income", "Don't know"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I managed to get this far, but then everything messes up when I try to add labels and group means of several columns in addition the overall mean:

```
lebanon %>%
  filter(!is.na(approval_gov)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(approval_gov)) +
  geom_density(fill = "steelblue", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(approval_gov), color = approval_gov),
             color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0:10)) +
  labs(title = " To what extent are you satisfied with the current government's performance?", 
       x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 20),
      plot.title = element_text(size = 32, hjust = 0),
      axis.title = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_text(size = 20, colour = "black"),
      axis.ticks.y = element_line(),
      panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank())
```

[image]

Any suggestions? :)

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved like so. Compute the wanted means and put them in one dataframe together with the group_labels. This dataframe can then be used both with `geom_vline` and `geom_text` (or `ggrepel::geom_label_repel`) to draw the lines and add the labels. Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

means <- list(
  all = summarise(lebanon, value = mean(approval_gov, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% mutate(group = "all"),
  gender = group_by(lebanon, gender) %>% summarise(value = mean(approval_gov, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% rename(group = gender),
  age_cat = group_by(lebanon, age_cat) %>% summarise(value = mean(approval_gov, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% rename(group = age_cat)) %>% 
  bind_rows()

lebanon %>%
  filter(!is.na(approval_gov)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(approval_gov)) +
  geom_density(fill = "steelblue", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(data = means, aes(xintercept=value, color = group),
             linetype="dashed", size=1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data = means, aes(x = value, y = .05, label = group)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0:10)) +
  labs(title = " To what extent are you satisfied with the current government's performance?", 
       x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 20),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 32, hjust = 0),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 20, colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work with the full dataset as it has some NAs for some categories, and it gives me this message: ```summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)```. And how do I show only certain values from a column...like only male and leave out female?

Comment: Hi @Nicosc. This is just a message introduced with dplyr 1.0.0 to inform that summarise ungroups the dataset after the computation. No warning. And no error.

Comment: ... concerning the NAs. Simply add na.rm = TRUE to the mean function. Sorry. Always forget about that. (;

Comment: Thanks! :) How do I filter across columns, for example if I only want to show males (but not females) and maybe only two of the age cohorts?

Comment: `means <- filter(means, !(group %in% c("Male"))` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks! Last question: the last code is when you want to remove one value, but if I want to select the values that I want to show, how do I do that? This makes it easier when working with variables with more than two levels. I tried ```means <- filter(means, (group %in% c("Male"))```, but that doesn't work.

Comment: You are completely right, e.g. `filter(means, group %in% c("Male", "all", "50-59"))` filter for Male, all and 50-59. Perhaps you filtered on the already filtered dataset? Maybe the best is to assign the filtered means dataset to a new var, e.g. `means_filtered <- filter(means, group %in% c("Male", "all", "50-59"))` and use `means_filtered` for plotting.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks! :)